# Percent value of each row in relation with the column sum in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which looks like this :

```
SELECT dbo.music_styles.music, (COUNT(dbo.people.id)* 100.00 / (SELECT SUM(dbo.people.id)))  AS nbStyle
FROM dbo.people_music_styles
INNER JOIN dbo.music_styles ON dbo.music_styles.id = dbo.people_music_styles.id_music_styles
WHERE dbo.people.age BETWEEN @age_min and @age_max 
AND dbo.people.gender = @gender
GROUP BY dbo.music_styles.music
ORDER BY nbStyle DESC
```

In the response I get a array with two columns:

- one with the name of the style (thanks to the join)
- another column with the number of times the style appears in the relational table regarding the parameter I set.

I want a third column with the value of the row regarding the total/sum of the column with the number of times the style appear.

Comment: Can you please tag your correct database T-sql or mySql ? i can't find table dbo.people in joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this will require fractions make sure to convert so it won't truncate to an integer:

```
(COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.music_styles.id) / CONVERT(FLOAT, COUNT(SELECT SUM(dbo.music_styles) FROM dbo.music_styles))) * 100
```

Let me know if this works, if not I'll be happy to explore further.

Comment: It's not really that, i will try another explanation. For example i have in the result of my query 5 style of music which appears each one 4 times in my relational table with the parameters i choose. So i want a third column with the percentage (in this case will be 20% for each) of each row regarding the sum of the column of this query ! I hope i'm clear !

Comment: @MatthieuRigaux please let me know if my latest edit worked. I'm ready to help.

Answer (score 0):

@CarlosBos i finally manage to find an answer that works using a part of your proposal ! 
Here is the code :

```
SELECT dbo.music_styles.music, COUNT(dbo.people.id) AS peopleID, CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(COUNT(dbo.people.id)* 100.00 / SUM(COUNT(dbo.people.id)) OVER (), 2)) AS Répartition
FROM dbo.people_music_styles
INNER JOIN dbo.people ON dbo.people.id = dbo.people_music_styles.id_people
INNER JOIN dbo.music_styles ON dbo.music_styles.id = dbo.people_music_styles.id_music_styles
WHERE dbo.people.age BETWEEN @age_min and @age_max 
AND dbo.people.gender = @gender
GROUP BY dbo.music_styles.music
ORDER BY peopleID DESC
```

Thanks a lot !